# Create valid Messaging Session with Apex for outbound WhatsApp message

Tags: apex, whatsapp

Today I have an Apex job that sends multiple messages every couple of minutes.

So.. if the receiver doesn't have a related MessagingEndUser, I create it before sending the message; I apply some bussiness rules and send a message with a custom Flow we created. Everything is ok, if the receiver interacts with the org WhatsApp MessagingChannel, he will receive every message.

But if he didn't Salesforce will try it, it creates the MessagingSession record, but it's created ended and Salesforce prints an error on the MessagingSession record "We can’t send this message because it timed out. You can start the new conversation when the user contacts you again.

I did search and didn't find any workaround or anyone saying something about it. At the end, I just need to send a message with Apex code, if there is no active Messaging Session too.

I already tried to create the MessagingSession before sending the message, but Salesforce just ignores the new record, create another one ended and doesn't send any message.